# How to add days or unlimited hours on cupertinoTimerPicker?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino

How to add days or unlimited hours to `CupertinoTimerPicker`?
or Is that any way to add hours and minutes without using `CupertinoTimerPicker`

```
  Widget time() {
    return CupertinoTimerPicker(
      mode: CupertinoTimerPickerMode.hm,
      minuteInterval: 1,
      secondInterval: 1,
      initialTimerDuration: initialtimer,
      onTimerDurationChanged: (Duration changedtimer) {
        setState(() {
          initialtimer = changedtimer;
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: I think you cannot because see here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTimerPicker-class.html

Comment: @Ravikumar do you know another option to select hours and minutes?